# Show equivalence of statements

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. Show that the following statements are equivalent for $f \in$ End$(V)$:

i) $f \in$ Gl$(V)$

ii) There exists a $g\in$ End$(V)$ with $g\circ f$ = id.

iii) There exists a $g\in$ End$(V)$ with $f\circ g$ = id.

iv) rg$(f) = \dim (V)$

My approach:

ii) $\implies$ $f$ is injective

iii) $\implies$ $f$ is surjective

Can I say that since $f$ is an automorphism iv) directly follows?

Can I use the isomorphism Aut$(V)\simeq$ Gl$(V)$ to show i) then?

Comment: Remember that if a linear map is injective it is automatically surjective if the dimensions of the domain and range are the same. Also if the dimensions of the domain and range space are the same the existence of a left hand inverse implies invert ability. The same goes for a right hand inverse.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** Use the dimension theorem: $\dim\ker(f)+\dim{\rm rg}(f)=\dim V$ if $f$ is a linear map from vector space $V$.

Comment: So as the map is linear, $\dim\ker(f) = 0 \implies ( 0 + ) \dim{\rm rg}(f) = \dim(V)$ ? I dont know how to use your second hint...

Comment: Yes, probably that's not needed here... i) says $f$ has a two-sided inverse, ii) says $f$ has a left inverse, i.e. $f$ is injective, i.e. $\ker f=0$, iii) says $f$ has a right inverse, show that it is equivalent to $f$ being surjective, i.e. ${\rm rg}\, f=V$. A consequence of the dimension theorem is that '$f$ is surjective $\iff\ \,f$ is injective', in the finite dimensional case, and that finishes the proof.